# Абстрактный класс или интерфейс?

Tags: java, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, интерфейс

У меня имееться два подобных класса `LowPathFilter` и `HighPathFilter`.

```
public class HighPathFilter {
private  int timeConstantInDenominator;

public HighPathFilter(int timeConstantInDenominator){
    this.timeConstantInDenominator=timeConstantInDenominator;
}

public String printLPF(){
    String equationForm = timeConstantInDenominator+"s / "+"( "+ timeConstantInDenominator +"s + "+ 1 +" )";
    return equationForm;
}
```

}

и

```
public class LowPathFilter {
private  int numerator;
private  int timeConstantInDenominator;
private  int variableInDenominator;

public LowPathFilter(int numerator,int timeConstantInDenominator,int variableInDenominator){
    this.numerator=numerator;
    this.timeConstantInDenominator=timeConstantInDenominator;
    this.variableInDenominator=variableInDenominator;
}

public String printLPF(){
    String equationForm = numerator+" / "+"( "+ timeConstantInDenominator +"s + "+ variableInDenominator +" )";
    return equationForm;
}
}
```

В данных классах будут еще 5 одинаковых методов для каждого класса, но они будут немного отличаться в реализации. К тому же появятся разные поля для каждого класса. Я хочу создать родителя - класс `Filter`, а мои два класса `LowPathFilter` и `HighPathFilter` будут его реализациями. Как мне это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если есть общая логика в разных классах то разумнее вынести ее в родителький абстрактный класс. Т.к. интерфейс вам не позволит это сделать, если не брать в расчет `default` методы

Так же, методы которые будут отличаться реализацией объявите как абстрактные

Comment: а то, что у меня разные поля будут в `lowPathFilter` и `HighPassFilter` , плюс разные параметры в конструкторах, как с этим быть?

Comment: По возможности вынесите и общие поля в класс родитель. Но если такой возможности нет, то оставляйся в классах потомках

Comment: Но в случае, если общих методов с одинаковой реализацией не будет - то лучше интерфейс, кмк.

Comment: огромное всем спасибо